# TouchableOpacity breaks styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm attempting to create navigation in React Native. I've made a custom component that consists of an image and some text. Before applying `TouchableOpacity` the styling works fine. But after I apply it to one of the components, this happens.

[image: The screen]

[All of the code can be found here, ready to run.](https://snack.expo.io/@floatba/first-navigation)

I'd like that the component titles *MojQR* doesn't deform, but stays like the rest of them. Currently, as seen in the code, the `TouchableOpacity` is **only** applied to *MojQR*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the styling you are using. When you set the dimensions (width, height) to take a percentage, it will take the percentage from the component that is wrapping it. That's why when you added `TouchableOpacity` it mess all the styling. You have 2 options, change the styling pattern you are using or make a simple change that can change the `width` dynamically from `MenuItem` like so:

```
//App.js

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchableContainer} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}>
  <MenuItem itemImage={require('./app/img/QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg.png')} children='Moj QR' isWrapped={true} />
</TouchableOpacity>
...

//And the styling inside your style object
  touchableContainer: {
    width: '50%'
  }
```

In the code above, you add that prop that will be used to change the styles in

```
//MenuItem.js
//change the wrapper for this one:
<View style={this.props.isWrapped ? {...styles.menuItem, width: '100%'} : styles.menuItem}>
...

//And add the flexGrow property to your styles.menuItem
    menuItem: {
        width: '50%',
        height: '33.3333%',
        padding: 10,
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
```